# Sending info from one batch file to another

Tags: batch-file

So I have 2 batch scripts running. File1 and File2. I want to type something into File2 and it will run `goto :START` in File1 then File2 will close. Is there anyway I can do this?

EDIT: I also need it to work in a loop

FILE2:

```
:LOOP
cls
echo do you want FILE1 to go to the start?
choice
if %ERRORLEVLE%==1 (
   SETS %VAR% in FILE1 to equal 1
   exit
)
goto :LOOP
```

FILE1:

```
:START
set /a VAR=0
cls
echo this is the start
pause>nul
goto :LOOP

:LOOP
cls
echo Looping...
if %VAR%==1 goto :START
goto :LOOP
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "I have 2 batch scripts running"? I ask because if `FILE1` is already running, you cannot inject into that process from `FILE2`, you can only run `FILE1` in another separate process. If `FILE2` was `call`ed from `FILE1` initially, then that may be a different scenario. Please provide more details with real world commands that we can copy and test. Currently what you've posted is unclear and possibly an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (nearly unknown) command `waitfor` is intended for synchronizing batchfiles over the network but works also on one computer between different `cmd` instances. It's like a "remote pause" on the receiving end.

File1.bat (receiving script)

```
@echo off
:START
echo this is the start. Waiting for signal to continue
waitfor GotoStart
goto :start
```

File2.bat (sending script)

```
@echo off
:start
echo press any key to send signal to file1
pause >nul
waitfor /si GotoStart
goto :start
```

Note: `waitfor` is part of Windows since Win7.

EDIT: the disadvantage is, that `waitfor` waits until the signal arrives (or a timeout occurs) and the script can't do anything other in that time.

Two instances can't interact directly with each other. But you can use a dummy file.
File1 (receiving): `if exist "%temp%\signal.tmp" (del "%temp%\signal.tmp & set "var=1")`
File2 (sending): `break>"%temp%\signal.tmp"`

Comment: Impressive! I'm surprised  to see a command that I never seen before

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i need something that can make FILE2 set a variable in FILE1 so i can have something like "if %VAR%==1 goto :START" in a loop in FILE1

Comment: Please see my edit. Does that pay the bill?

Comment: @Stephan I should be able to use that solution. I will have to create the temp file in %APPDATA% or something but it should work. Sorry for having such specific circumstances.